# How to make .env available during Firebase deploy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently tried to deploy a function that executed some code in one of its module's root levels, and it failed because the code depended on a `process.env` variable.

My env variables are provided via `.env.[project-name]` files that live in the root of the deployed package. These variables are available at runtime whenever the functions execute after being deployed, but so it seems not during deployment.

The execution happens during this stage of firebase-tools `deploy` command:

> Loading and analyzing source code for codebase [my-codebase] to determine what to deploy

Is this intentional? Is there anything I can do to make the env variables from my files available there? Or is it considered harmful to execute code on the module root level?

I used to use Firebase `functions:config`, and I seem to remember that it wasn't a problem there to use env variables at the module level. In any case, I wouldn't want to go back to using that, because I am gradually migrating to 2nd gen functions and those are not compatible.

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  The env vars are only available during function execution.  Note that if you need to use an env var for configuring the function itself, there is a [special way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#params) to get those vars.  Otherwise, you should not use process.env at the global scope of your code.  Lazy init instead as shown in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up Doug! I do see that parameterized configuration mentions that the vars are available at both runtime and deploy time, but the section on dotenv doesn't address this, so I think it would be helpful to mention the difference there.

Comment: The docs I linked to in my first comment make it clear that you have to use `defineX` methods to declare your vars, which gives you a "parameter", on which you call `value` let the SDK know you want it to use the env. "*When deploying a function with parameterized configuration variables, the Firebase CLI first attempts to load their values from local .env files.*"

Comment: That much was clear to me, but the section about regular env files doesn't seem to mention the scope of the variables / that they are not available during deployment. It could be made more apparent I think. I skipped reading about parameterized configuration because I didn't think I needed it after reading about env files.

Comment: That sounds like feedback for the authors of the documentation.  Use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I will. And sorry for assuming you could pass it on somehow. In my mind, you were associated with Google :)